# jQuery adding sortable / draggable to isotope masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-isotope, jquery-ui-sortable

Good morning,

I've a problem concerning the jQuery plugin `isotope`.

[image]

As you can see [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29UUd/) I have a grid with dynamic layout (you can click on a div and the size and the layout changes).
Now I want to be able to sort the `items` in an other order by using jQuerys `sortable`.
Adding this to the code:

```
$container.sortable({
   items: '.item'
});
```

Will make it draggable but without any sortable function.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA -
With best regards,
frgtv10

Comment: jQuery Isotope does not support draggable elements, see http://metafizzy.co/blog/mythical-drag-drop-multi-column-grid-plugin/

Comment: This is something I want very badly! I am considering hitting up the author in an attempt to collaborate and make this happen! It would be the best thing since sliced bread!

Answer (score 9):

MetaFizzy has a new plugin out called [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/), which might do what you want.

See here for more: http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use my modification of gridster.js with addition of resize. (also masonry & draggable included)

https://github.com/evaldsurtans/gridster.js

Example:
http://evalds.lv/gridster

Comment: Example URL for this is a 404 now.

Comment: Thank you, I will get it back online

Comment: I have just tested in windows + chrome // what is you configuration? you can also add bugfixes and submit them in github

Answer (score 1):

I give you a link for jsfiddle... check out that they used both jquery draggable and isotope.

http://jsfiddle.net/ganeshgaxy/yL3Lu/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inner').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.gravity'
    });
    var list = $('#inner');
    list.sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item ...
```

Comment: Not really a masonry thing as all elements have the same size

Comment: LGTM !  It works fine !  @Ben: it's work with variable height as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible but with limitations. Take a look at
http://tyler-designs.com/masonry-ui/

Comment: and the isotope / masonry author's related blog post: http://metafizzy.co/blog/mythical-drag-drop-multi-column-grid-plugin/